# Get environment variables from operating system

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to validate & deploy ARM templates via my CI. Is it possible to have an ARM template lookup the value of a parameter in an OS environment variable?  i.e.

`"image": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Docker image"
       }`

In this case, it would be nice if ARM could find the value of "image" from an OS environment called $ARM_IMAGE (or whatever).  I don't want to use a parameters file because of the possibility of sensitive data.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that, unless you script it. so you would pull environment variables and pass them as parameters (not parameters file) to the deployment.